# Is it haram for a man to watch an unveiled women on TV?

Tags: halal-haram, women, men, non-mahram

When we watch television we constantly keep our eyes on a person in the TV show.

> “O Ali! Do not turn round to look! The first look is all right but you have no right for the second look.”

Based on this hadith it would seem that a man can only look once, as it is an accident that cannot be prevented. But what if a man is watching TV? He will repeatedly look at the unveiled women, so would this be haram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the hadith that you quote is very clear about lowering the gaze.

Shaykh, Muhammad ibn Saalih al-‘Uthaymeen said regarding the issue:

> Watching television is divided into three categories:
>
> 1) Watching that which is of benefit for one's religion and beneficial
>   matters of this life, however it is conditional on it not becoming a
>   means to see the haraam, for example, **the woman sits looking at and
>   enjoying seeing the man giving the news, because this would be fitnah.
>   The same applies to the man, looking at a beautiful woman giving the
>   news with enjoyment, this is a fitnah.**
>
> 2) Seeing that which is harmful to one's religion is haraam because
>   the believer is obligated to protect himself and his family in the
>   religion.
>
> 3) That which is of no benefit or no harm is nonsense which does not
>   befit the believer and the believer should not waste his time with it.

**Source:** [Watching TV](http://abdurrahman.org/sins/TV-YesorNo.pdf)

The Messenger of Allah, may the prayers and blessings of Allah be upon him, said:

> ''The zinâ' of the eyes is the gaze (at that which is unlawful, e.g.
>   nudity); the zinâ' of the ears is to listen (to talks of nudity which
>   excites the carnal desired); the zinâ' of the tongue is to speak (what
>   is evil); the zinâ' of the hand is to touch (the female which is
>   unlawful to you); the zinâ' of the feet is to walk (towards
>   immorality); the zinâ' of the heart is to desire (what is unlawful),
>   and it is the private parts which either commits or shuns the actual
>   act of fornication." **(Muslim 4/1397 no. 6421, 6422)**

Answer (score 2):

According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27fari_jurisprudence) if there is fear of falling in sin and looking for enjoy then yes it is Haram.

> Question: Is it permissible to look at non-Muslim women who are naked
>   or half-naked in television and its like for the purpose of fulfilling
>   the inquisitive nature with no guarantee whether or not sexual desire
>   will be aroused? Is it permissible to look at them in the streets not
>   for the purpose mentioned above but for arousing [the sexual desire
>   of] the husband towards his wife?
>
> Answer: It is not permissible to look with lust at the naked live
>   scenes, on television, etc. Rather, based on compulsory precaution,
>   one must refrain from it at all times.

---

**Reference:**

[A Code of Practice For Muslims in the West](http://www.sistani.org/index.php?p=251364&id=46&pid=2069) by Grand Ayatollah Sistani

Comment: i mean for entertainment not arousal, as in the news with an unveiled news anchor or a comedy with a women as the main charecter

Comment: @NesreenA entertainment is the entering gate to arousal. anyway one himself can understand if there is fear to falling in arousal or not. a real believers avoid preliminary of sin. http://tanzil.net/#24:21 O you who have believed, do not follow the footsteps of Satan. And whoever follows the footsteps of Satan - indeed, he enjoins immorality and wrongdoing... http://www.al-islam.org/nahj/193.htm

Comment: @NesreenA I agree with Ahmadi. Entertainment in Islam has very good guidance. You are just entertaining now, but one can never firmly say that, this innocent entertainment will not becomes something that was not intended. So, is the general guidance of Allah, to lower the gaze

Comment: its just because his example said that the man was pourposly doing it for arousal i agree that entertainment is oftenly because of arousal